# A fiber bundle of the Euclidean space over an orbifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles, fibration, orbifolds

Consider a fiber bundle $p: F\hookrightarrow
 E \to B$, where $E$ and $F$ are smooth manifolds and $B$ is a smooth orbifold. More precisely, each point $b \in B$ has an orbifold chart $U=\tilde U/\Gamma$ and a finite group $\Lambda$ acting freely on $\tilde U \times F$ such that $p^{-1}(U)=(\tilde U \times F)/\Lambda$ and the projection map $\pi_1:\tilde U \times F \to \tilde U$ is $(\Lambda, \Gamma)$-equivariant. Hence the following diagram is commutative:
$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 & \tilde U \times F & \ra{} & p^{-1}(U) &  \\
 & \da{\pi_1} & & \da{p} &  \\
& \tilde U & \ra{} & U & 
\end{array}
$$

If $E$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ and $F$ is compact, can we prove that the fiber bundle must be trivial? That is, $F$ is a single point.